# PHP while loop never exits

Tags: php, oracle-call-interface

I have a while loop inside a foreach loop. The while loop never exits and crashes the server, I can't figure out why. Here's a condensed version of the code.

```
foreach( $final_plates as $key => $value) { 
   $Plate_No = ($value['plate_no']);
   $sql = "SELECT J.PLATE_NO FROM PLATE_LOGS J WHERE (J.PLATE_NO = " . $Plate_No . ")";
   $db->query($sql);
   while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($db2->result)) {  
       echo $row['PLATE_NO'] . "</br>"; 
   }                      
}
```

If I use the following statement instead of the while loop, the first record will be found without any problem

```
$row = oci_fetch_assoc($db->result);
```

I am using a class to connect to the database that I didn't write. I'm also new to programming. Here's some code from the class.

```
 function connect(){

    $this->connection = oci_connect($this->user, $this->password, $this->db) or die("Connection Failed: " . oci_error());
    if(!$this->connection)
    {
     return false;
    }
}   

function query($sql){
  // Query SQL
    $this->result = oci_parse($this->connection, $sql) or die ("SQL ERROR" . oci_error($this->connection));
    oci_execute($this->result) or die ("SQL ERROR" . oci_error($this->result));
}
```

Comment: So what is the `$row` value when it's looped? PS: consider using `J.PLATE_NO IN (val1, val2, ...)` instead of using N queries

Comment: why are you using `$db2->result` ?

Comment: Try $row = oci_fetch_row($db->result);

Comment: $db2 != $db ! you have a typo.

Comment: $db2 is a typo, i'm using $db

Comment: @zerkms. The row value stays the same and never changes when I echo it out. The plate_no never gets incremented in the foreach loop because the while loop is not exiting

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:mysql] and [tag:mysqli]?

Comment: Your combination of `oci_*` functions and what seems to be a database wrapper is a bit confusing, I would guess you'd need something like `while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($db)) {` or `while ($row = $db->fetch()) {` but you should probably rewrite to use *or* only `oci_*` functions *or* go `$db->...` all the way.

Comment: what is $db ? did you mixing procedural oci_* with PDO ?

Comment: you are assigning result of fetch to $row, will there be any true or false to stop it?

Comment: I've added the code for the sql class, although it looks like I messed up the formatting, it's hard to read.

Comment: Seems to me it would make more sense to have the results returned as an array by the `query()` function.